# Textangular not sending inline styles to server on post

Tags: angularjs

I'm using textangular in an angular app and it works fine except when posting the formatted html to the server it strips out all the inline styles. Example, `<p style="text-align: right">some text</p>` becomes `<p>some text</p>`

Why does this happen and am I missing something like ng-bind.html?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Angular Sanitize` in your project?? if you do it may be the problem because angular sanitize prevents scripts, events and inline styles to be displayed, why styles you may ask, cuz styles can be used to inject javascript as well as events or script tags:

```
<div style="background: url('javascript:alert(XSS)')">
```

This is to prevent malicious code to executed unless you explicitly tell your app your code can be trusted (carefull with that!, generally no user input is considered a trusted source), specifically by using the $sce module like this:

```
$sce.trustAsHtml(my_html_code_var)
```

see the docs below for more info:

See Doc here: [Sanitize Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

PS. textangular got its own sanitize to manage some of that issues with regular sanitize, from textangulr github:

> NOTE: Our textAngular-sanitize.js and angular.js's angular-sanitize.js are the SAME file, you must include one or the other but not both. We highly recommend using textAngular-sanitize.js as it loosens some parts of the sanitizer that are far too strict for our uses and adds some more features we need.

Comment: Im not using sanitize, maybe I need to use textAngular-sanitize.js in the project?

Comment: perhaps, also check the network console to see if youre sending the content with the style props and reciving it with them, and a plu ker or jsfiddle example should help us find the answer as well :)

Comment: im not able to do a jsfiddle or plunkr but I have this screencast showing the network console: http://screencast.com/t/VZGmg61Ify

Comment: hmm thats odd, obviously the sanization is in the client side, but would you double check the if sanitize extension is in your project, because trying to build a plunker for me using textangular do not work unless i include the sanitize, check here: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/tt7PJaJilqKm3CblzrgC?p=preview)

Comment: Strife86 is correct in that textAngular will not run without a sanitizer being loaded as a script. TextAngular itself will pull it in as long as the javascript is loaded.

As for inline styles, we have a couple of ways around this, our current whitelist is small and here: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/master/src/textAngular-sanitize.js#L499-L537.

Also look at this issue if you absolutely trust your users: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/233